# Создание визуализации к констольному приложению python

Tags: python, sql, json

есть консольное приложение для создания обьектов,структура данных в виде дерева, например:магазин хранит полку, полка хранит коробку, информация об обьекте  и его дочерних элементах хранится в json. Подскажите пожалуста библиотеку в которой можно реализовать отрисовку и редактирование объектов, заранее спасибо.